# import ip packet via hex dump

Tags: wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I have a hex dump generated using gdb. I have generated the dump that wireshark can understand using "od -Ax -tx1 -v". But when I open in the wireshark tool the packet doesn't get recognized properly. I think wireshark is trying to read the ethernet frame while the buffer has data from IP header. Is there a way to indicate wireshark to parse hexdump assuming fro IP header.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`text2pcap`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/text2pcap.html).  There are 2 basic approaches you can take:

1. Add a dummy Ethernet header using the `-e <l3pid>` option, or
2. Set the encapsulation type of the converted pcap file to [link-layer type](https://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes.html) LINKTYPE_RAW using the `-l 101` option.

Comment: I'm still unable to get it right. This is my hex dump.

`000000 45 c0 00 36 00 00 00 00 01 67 b2 e8 c0 a8 65 03
000010 e0 00 00 0d 20 00 b7 3d 00 01 00 02 00 69 00 02
000020 00 04 01 f4 09 c4 00 13 00 04 00 00 00 01 00 14
000030 00 04 95 22 87 45
000036`

Comment: Have you tried properly formatting the bytes according to the example provided in the `text2pcap` man page?  Doing so results in a successful conversion of the data you provided to a pcap file using either method I described.